How to delete all rows from all tables in DB file using FMDB
I'm trying to create a common method to delete all rows from all DB files in my project.
I don't want to store and pass all tables names, so it should work only with a DB file path.
I tried to get all tables from the DB file via this code:
    guard
        let path = getDBPath(for: .contacts),
        let dbQueue = FMDatabaseQueue(path: path)
    else { return }
    
    dbQueue.inDatabase { fmdb in
        do {
            let resultSet = try fmdb.executeQuery(
                "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'",
                values: nil
            )
            // what is next?
        } catch {
            // log error
        }
    }

But I can't figure out what I have to do after fmdb.executeQuery.
Where do I need to call "DELETE FROM \(tableName)"?

Well, I managed it finally:
      let resultSet = try fmdb.executeQuery(
          "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE '%object%'", // I use `AND name LIKE '%object%'` to not clear any internal (system) tables, all my own entities have `object` word in their names
          values: []
      )
                
      while resultSet.next() {
          if let table = resultSet.string(forColumn: "name") {
              try fmdb.executeUpdate(
                  "DELETE FROM \(table)",
                  values: []
              )
          }
      }


This is the way. The only improvement I can think of is maybe put the table list into an array instead of iterating it over a result set (which might help with locking in SQLite?), and also starting a transaction before the execute update. That might make it a little faster as well.
